# Can't verify CSRF token! Angular 2 & spring security

Tags: java, spring, servlets, angular, spring-security

We're trying to implement a simple user login with angular 2 and spring security. But we are getting a 403 status back with the response:

> {"timestamp":1478525053048,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.","path":"/login"}

login.html:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <hr>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="user" type="text" name="user" [(ngModel)]="loginData.user" required><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Passwort:</label>
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.passwordLogin" required>
</div>
<!--<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />-->
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" (click)="login()">
```

http-service.ts:

```
    login(username, pwd){
    console.log(username, pwd);
    var json = JSON.stringify({'password':pwd,'username':username});
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('authorization', 'Basic');
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', json, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
// @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("loaded config");
    http.httpBasic() //
            .and() //
            .authorizeRequests() //
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login")//
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")//
            .successHandler(successHandler()).failureHandler(failureHandler()).and()//
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf()//
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());//
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("OK");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
        }
    };
}

private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("Authentication failure");
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        }

    };
}
```

CsrfHeaderFilter.java:

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
        final String token = csrf.getToken();
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

The call:
[Headers etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WXRR.png)

[loadOfLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AHDm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're dividing your project into Front-End project (AngularJS) which can be hosted by a Javascript Web server, and to a Back-End (Spring/Java) project,

You should start consider to use OAuth2 security instead of regular Spring security.

OAuth2 will give your front-end the ability to communicate safely with your other services according to authorizations rules. On behalf of your end users.

That will also leave the CSRF protection on front-end AngularJS side only, without the need to do it cross Java Spring.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using JWT for stateless authentication with Angular 2 and spring boot. A simple way to setup the angular side:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

For spring boot you can generate a scaffold of a spring boot example that possesses jwt security from java hipster:
https://jhipster.github.io/